# Customizer_register not saving custom setting to database

Tags: theme-customizer, settings-api

I'm currently trying to work on a WordPress theme based on [Sage](https://roots.io/sage/). The stage I'm at is creating custom controls to display on the customize screen for WordPress where you typically change things like the site title or theme colors if you're an end user.

It seems that the new setting I'm trying to add with `add_setting` isn't actually creating a database entry (Calling `get_theme_mod` on that particular setting returns nothing). I'm thinking that it has something to do with the add_control method but I've checked the [WordPress Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference%5CWP_Customize_Manager%5Cadd_control) on this and I have it matching as far I can tell.

```
namespace Roots\Sage\Customizer;

use Roots\Sage\Assets;

/**
 * Add customization settings for the theme
 */
function customize_register($wp_customize) {
  //////////////////////////
  // WIDGET STYLE OPTIONS //
  //////////////////////////
  $wp_customize->add_section( 'widget_style_section', array(
     'title'  => __('Widget Styling', __NAMESPACE__),
     'priority' => 115,
  ));

  $wp_customize->add_setting( 'widget_list_style', array(
     'default' => 'hide',
     'transport' => 'postMessage',
  ));

  $wp_customize->add_control( 'widget_list_style_control', array(
      'label' => __( 'Display List Style?', __NAMESPACE__),
      'Description' => __('Removes the symbols next to bulleted and    unbulleted lists in Widgets', __NAMESPACE__),
      'section' => 'widget_style_section',
      'settings' => 'widget_list_style',
      'type'    => 'radio', // TODO: CONTROL IS CONFUSED ABOUT WHAT TYPE IT IS, THATS WHY NO REFRESH
      'choices' => array(
           'hide' => __('Hide'),
           'show' => __('Show'),
       ),
  ));

  // Add postMessage support
  $wp_customize->get_setting('blogname')->transport = 'postMessage';
  $wp_customize->get_setting('blogdescription')->transport = 'postMessage';

  // TEST - To see if widget_list_style is storing properly
  echo get_theme_mod('widget_list_style');
}

add_action('customize_register', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\customize_register');
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code sample is that the setting is using `widget_` as the prefix. This is a reserved prefix for *widgets*, per the [customizer handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/customizer-objects/#settings):

> **Important:** Do not use a setting ID that looks like `widget_*`, `sidebars_widgets[*]`, `nav_menu[*]`, or `nav_menu_item[*]`. These setting ID patterns are reserved for widget instances, sidebars, nav menus, and nav menu items respectively. If you need to use “widget” in your setting ID, use it as a suffix instead of a prefix, for example “`homepage_widget`”.

Here is the modified code which works as expected:

```
<?php

namespace Roots\Sage\Customizer;

use Roots\Sage\Assets;

/**
 * Add customization settings for the theme
 */
function customize_register($wp_customize) {
    //////////////////////////
    // WIDGET STYLE OPTIONS //
    //////////////////////////
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'style_section_widget', array(
        'title'  => __('Widget Styling', __NAMESPACE__),
        'priority' => 115,
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'list_style_widget', array(
        'default' => 'hide',
        'transport' => 'postMessage',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control( 'widget_list_style_control', array(
        'label' => __( 'Display List Style?', __NAMESPACE__),
        'Description' => __('Removes the symbols next to bulleted and    unbulleted lists in Widgets', __NAMESPACE__),
        'section' => 'style_section_widget',
        'settings' => 'list_style_widget',
        'type'    => 'radio',
        'choices' => array(
            'hide' => __('Hide'),
            'show' => __('Show'),
        ),
    ));

    // Add postMessage support
    $wp_customize->get_setting('blogname')->transport = 'postMessage';
    $wp_customize->get_setting('blogdescription')->transport = 'postMessage';
}

add_action('customize_register', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\customize_register', 11);
```

Note also that I changed the priority for `customize_register` from 10 (the default) to 11 since the `blogname` and `blogdescription` settings may not be registered at that point.

Answer (score -1):

From [Theme_Customization_API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API):
To add your own options to the customizer, you need to use a minimum of 2 hooks:

[customize_register](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/customize_register)
This hook allows you define new customizer panels, sections, settings, and controls.

[wp_head](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head)
This hook allows you to output custom-generated CSS so that your changes show up correctly on the live website.

So your `customize_register` action look like(replace your theme name with *mytheme*):

```
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
   //All our sections, settings, and controls will be added here
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
```

Next, you need to define your settings, then your sections, then your controls (controls need a section and a setting to function).

**Note**: Only set this to '*postMessage*' if you are writing custom *Javascript* to control the Theme Customizer's live preview.

Comment: I'm calling the customize_register hook, the problem is that after that, the add_setting and add_control functions arn't resulting in 'widget_list_style' being saved to the database.